Visual Studio Code вылетает без ошибок
Нигде нету про это информации, VS Code не может запуститься, провисает 1 секунду серая панель (программа появляется) и пропадает, не уведомляя об ошибках.
Некоторые параметры:
OC: Windows 10 22h2
